# MongoDB aggregation : I want to extract the most expensive genre from Movie, I am able to calculate that genre but I cannot extract it's title

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

MongoDB aggregation : I want to extract the most expensive genre from Movie, I am able to calculate that genre but I cannot extract it's title

```
Movie.aggregate([
            {
               $unwind: '$genre'
            }, {
                $group: {
                    _id: "$genre",
                    numOfMovies: {$sum: 1},
                    // movieTitles: { $push: '$title'}
                    genrePrice: { $sum: '$price' },
                }
            },
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: '$_id',
                    topPricedGenre: {$max: '$genrePrice'},
                }
            }
            
        ]);
```

by using above query I can extract the most expensive genre but I also want to extract it's title.....
I am getting this output:

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "lenght": 20,
  "data": [
    {
      "_id": "Musical",
      "topPricedGenre": 75201
    },
    {
      "_id": "Fantasy",
      "topPricedGenre": 100296
    },
    {
      "_id": "Documentary",
      "topPricedGenre": 167574
    },
    {
      "_id": "War",
      "topPricedGenre": 88227
    },
    {
      "_id": "(no genres listed)",
      "topPricedGenre": 6375
    },
    {
      "_id": "Western",
      "topPricedGenre": 52622
    },
    {
      "_id": "Children",
      "topPricedGenre": 54527
    },
    {
      "_id": "Mystery",
      "topPricedGenre": 102575
    },
    {
      "_id": "Crime",
      "topPricedGenre": 141468
    },
    {
      "_id": "Comedy",
      "topPricedGenre": 456751
    },
    {
      "_id": "Horror",
      "topPricedGenre": 181037
    },
    {
      "_id": "Sci-Fi",
      "topPricedGenre": 100986
    },
    {
      "_id": "Drama",
      "topPricedGenre": 796831
    },
    {
      "_id": "Action",
      "topPricedGenre": 212681
    },
    {
      "_id": "Film-Noir",
      "topPricedGenre": 16103
    },
    {
      "_id": "Adventure",
      "topPricedGenre": 132670
    },
    {
      "_id": "Romance",
      "topPricedGenre": 267585
    },
    {
      "_id": "IMAX",
      "topPricedGenre": 9471
    },
    {
      "_id": "Animation",
      "topPricedGenre": 46687
    },
    {
      "_id": "Thriller",
      "topPricedGenre": 245489
    }
  ]
}
```

I am expecting this result, can anyone help me:

```
{
      "_id": "Drama",
      "topPricedGenre": 796831
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB can compare documents also [see this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-type-comparison-order/#objects)

Using the accumulator like bellow will keep the max price and the title of them movie.Its like get the max price, first and only if 2 movies equal max price, then get the max title.

If you try it and problems happen if you can give initial data, so we can test and give a complete query.

```js
{$max: {"maxPrice" : "$genrePrice"
        "title" :"$title"}}
```